# spacemacs: LatexMk not recognised when building latex

Tags: spacemacs, latex

I am trying to build a `LaTeX` file from inside `spacemacs`.

I have `LatexMk` installed with `MiKtex`.

I have tried `SPC m b` to build a `test.tex` file and it does nothing.

Doing `C-h C-l` shows:

```
Running `LatexMk' on `test' with ``latexmk -pdf --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -file-line-error  "test.tex"''
'latexmk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Jul 23 00:15:25
```

This is strange because running the command `latexmk -pdf --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -file-line-error  "test.tex"` at a command prompt works fine!

What am I missing?

Comment: it might depend on how you open emacs. If you double click on an icon, it might not have your environment variables like your path, etc. Try opening it from a shell, and if it works, that is the problem.

Comment: @JohnKitchin I open from command line. Is there a way to check path from inside spacemac?

Comment: You could try echoing the path as a shell command. Or see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath and http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html and related pages.